# grep command in Solaris x86 to Capture Special character

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, opensolaris

I want to capture perticular string i.e. "UPDATE kplustp..Service SET Service_Name = "PositionService", ServiceType = 'Z', HostName = "abcd" " in log file with perticular path /home/abc/xyz.log

I am using below command to do

```
grep -i "UPDATE kplustp..Service SET Service_Name = "PositionService", ServiceType = 'Z'" /home/adc/xyz.log
```

But it is not working, may be because of special characters in string.

How to do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have my solaris box at hand, but try this:

```
grep -i 'UPDATE kplustp..Service SET Service_Name = "PositionService", ServiceType = \'Z\'' /home/adc/xyz.log
```

Comment: Sorry no success, It is giving output as Unmatched "

Comment: answer updated, using single quotes - and backslash to render the embedded single quotes as literals.

Comment: Hi Thanks, it works for me. Can we capture two strings in a perticular file. For ex my 1st string is "job has started" and 2nd string is "Job completed successfully" in same log file xyz.log

Comment: Oh good. I don't think you can do this with one grep command. It is possible with sed. Would that do? BTW it would be nice to upvote and tick the answer - thanks.